# How to remove traces of uninstalled app from Windows 10 notifications settings?

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-10

We have an application that sends toast notifications to user in Windows 10.

We have received feedback from our clients that when our application is uninstalled, traces from toast notifications are still present in Windows 10 notifications & actions settings:

[image: Notification traces]

It doesn't disappear after reboot. We have no idea how to remove it from there, and it seems to be no useful information on the Internet.

We need to know if there is a way to do this, or we should report this as bug to Microsoft.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/remove-an-uninstalled-app-from-the-notification/6cb57f86-23fd-4261-8922-e49f344095e5?auth=1

Comment: @volatilevar This article states that starting with Windows 10 Version 1607 it requires to mess with sqlite database in the user profile to remove these entries. We need a developer solution, not a hack )